# SQL Server float as user friendly value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a column of type float in one of my tables in a SQL Server database.

This table is populated by different ways, via scripts, services etc.
I want to export values from this table but in some cases values are not user friendly.

For example someone inserted value : 0.00000001, but when I select the value appears like: 1E-08. I've tried with cast to decimal, but I don't have the precision, it's not static, could varies on different rows.

I'm looking for equivalent like in C# - `Convert.ToDecimal(value)` that works without specifying the precision

Comment: If you don't want floating point values, why are you using a `float`?

Comment: *"I'm looking for equivalent like in C# - Convert.ToDecimal(value) that works without specifying the precision"* There is no such thing in SQL Server. Defining a `decimal` without a precision and scale uses the default precision and scale of `18` and `0` respectively, per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16); which would result in `1e-08` being stored as `0`.

Comment: The appearance of the value depends solely on your client, so if you're seeing `1E-08` it's because whatever client you're using picks that format. So first check if you can (or should) reconfigure your client to just use a different display format, and only if that's not an option can you use things like `STR` and `FORMAT`. Even then you need to specify the desired format *somehow*, including, at the very least, maximum precision. For example, `SELECT FORMAT(0.00000001e, '0.' + REPLICATE('#', 20))` to format with up to 20 digits.